# Web based Iphone / Android app

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications

I am considering developing an Iphone/Android application but I want the information on it to be live and uniform between platforms... Therefore it seemed logical to me to make it web based. I would however like to be able to achieve certain non web based functions such as adding events to the calendar and gps locations on the the mapping sortware.

My questions are:

1. Can I make a web based
   application that does not visually
   show in a browser?
2. Can I add additional functions  that
   are not natively available in a
   browser e.g <a href="#"
   title="adddate:110911"/>Add to
   Calendar</a>
3. Would it be a lot of work to make
   such an app as the majority is web
   based (I mostly progam in PHP so
   coding for Android and Iphone will
   take me some time to get my head
   around).

All of the questions are for both Iphone and Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a cross platform solution like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) (with UI [sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) on top of it).

Answer (score 0):

You can have an app that is a thin shell over the system browser, and exposes the non-Web bits of functionality to the contained HTML via JavaScript interfaces. You will still need two different codebases for iPhone and Android, but the essense of the app will be still webby.

There's no way to manage the system calendar from Web apps neither on iPhone nor on Android, AFAIK.

Comment: Regarding the calendar ... I did write a bit in my post that seems to have disappeared. I was thinking of making some functions within the application which can be trigger by the html e.g <a href="#" title="calendar:110111">add to calendar</a>.... would that be possible?

Comment: In the regular Web browser - no. In a custom app that loads a Web page into a browser window - you can expose your functionality to the JavaScript as a global JavaScript object. Then you can do JavaScript links of the form: <a href="javascript:myapp.DoSomething();">Hello world</a>

Comment: Not really on android. Since there's no guarantee which calander app, if any, the user has installed. And There's no documented API for the google calendar app (you can use the google calendar web api though).

Comment: Be very careful about allowing webpages in your browser apps to activate your code via javascript calls. If you aren't ensuring that your server is the only thing that ever supplies the code you're exposing a security hole that anyone who learns about could use. In this instance it sounds like someone could use your app to browse to a webpage and if that webpage knows how they could change the user's calendar just by putting the proper javascript calls in.

Comment: @Starlin: Your HTML code disappeared from the post because it wasn't escaped.  I escaped it and it shows now.  Just FYI.